# Elastic data restore from S3

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch backup taken into S3. But I am not able to restore it using any of the commands mentioned below.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/elasticsearch/snap-dev_1/_restore

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/snap-deliveryreports_june2016bk/elasticsearch/_restore
```

I can see the files in S3:

[image]

What is the command to restore the data shown in the image?

---

update:

The following command is successful (returns *acknowleged: true*)
It means access key, secret key, bucket name and region is correct.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository?verify=true&pretty' -d'
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "todel162",
    "region": "us-east-1"
  }
}'
```

I guess I only need to know how to use restore snapshot command.

Comment: adding your configuration files and what error you get when you try to restore will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cat recovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/cat-recovery.html) API to monitor your restore status, as restoring just piggybacks on the regular recovery mechanism of elasticsearch, so check if you see anything using those APIs.