# Restore data from S3

Tags: elasticsearch

I do already have es backup in S3 and the bucket name for e.g. is "some-bucket".
I tried to restore the data...

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository1" -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "some-bucket"
  }
}'
```

I got the response like this...

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Now when I try to restore data, I get repo missing exception ...

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository1/dev_1/_restore?pretty=true&wait_for_completion=true"

{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "snapshot_restore_exception",
        "reason" : "[my_s3_repository1:dev_1] snapshot does not exist"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "snapshot_restore_exception",
    "reason" : "[my_s3_repository1:dev_1] snapshot does not exist"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I guess I am not suppling the snapshot name correctly. I referred to this post and tried all possibilities.

https://medium.com/@rcdexta/periodic-snapshotting-of-elasticsearch-indices-f6b6ca221a0c

How do I restore data from S3?

---

Update:

I can see 2 empty snapshots. But I am sure there is a lot of data on S3

```
 $ curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/snapshots/my_s3_repository1?v
id     status start_epoch start_time end_epoch  end_time duration indices successful_shards failed_shards total_shards
snap1 SUCCESS 1518343272  10:01:12   1518343272 10:01:12     52ms       0                 0             0            0
snap2 SUCCESS 1518343818  10:10:18   1518343818 10:10:18     64ms       0                 0             0            0

$ curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository1/snap1/_restor
e?pretty=true&wait_for_completion=true"
{
  "snapshot" : {
    "snapshot" : "snap1",
    "indices" : [ ],
    "shards" : {
      "total" : 0,
      "failed" : 0,
      "successful" : 0
    }
  }
}

$ curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository1/snap2/_restor
e?pretty=true&wait_for_completion=true"
{
  "snapshot" : {
    "snapshot" : "snap2",
    "indices" : [ ],
    "shards" : {
      "total" : 0,
      "failed" : 0,
      "successful" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

---

Update 2:

My data is in a folder within the bucket. The base_path parameter does not seem to work though.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository1" -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "todel162",
"base_path": "elasticsearch/indices/dbaug"
  }
}'
```

The backup files are pretty old (June 2016) if that matters.

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/snapshots/my_s3_repository1?v`

Comment: How do I use base_path? This does not seem to be working ... "base_path": "elasticsearch/indices/dbaug"

Comment: So you have 2 empty snapshots. Not much to restore there :-) Are you sure you've set up the repo correctly with the proper bucket ID and access/secret keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic data restore from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139312/elastic-data-restore-from-s3)